# XML Element not showing in output when using XML Writer in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm trying to create a simple xml file in C# that is a Playlist for vlc media player. I'm new to xml and I just can't seem to figure out why the tracklist element is not showing up in the output. The ending tag for tracklist shows up but no beginning tag. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
   XmlTextWriter xmldoc = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\Jamie\Documents\Playlist.xspf", Encoding.UTF8);
   xmldoc.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   xmldoc.Indentation = 2;
   xmldoc.WriteStartDocument(true);                                //<xml start>
        xmldoc.WriteStartElement("Playlist");                           //<Playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vls="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/">
            xmldoc.WriteStartAttribute("version");
                xmldoc.WriteValue(1);
                xmldoc.WriteEndAttribute(); 
            xmldoc.WriteStartAttribute("xmlns");
                xmldoc.WriteValue("http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
                xmldoc.WriteEndAttribute(); 
            xmldoc.WriteStartAttribute("xmlns:vls");
                xmldoc.WriteValue("http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/");
                xmldoc.WriteEndAttribute(); 
            xmldoc.WriteStartElement("title");                                  //<title>
                xmldoc.WriteString("Playlist");                                        //Playlist
            xmldoc.WriteEndElement();                                           //</title>             
            xmldoc.WriteStartElement("tracklist");                              //<tracklist>
            xmldoc.WriteEndElement();                                           //</tracklist>
            xmldoc.WriteEndElement();                                       //</Playlist>
     xmldoc.WriteEndDocument();                                      //<xml end>
     xmldoc.Dispose();
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"xmlns:vls="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <tracklist />
</Playlist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct: `<tracklist />` denotes an empty tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was driving me crazy.